# Features folders in Angular and MVC / Web API application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angularjs, asp.net-web-api

I am working on a project with ASP.NET MVC, Web API and Angular JS.

I am considering changing the project structure from classic MVC (folder wrap files of the same type - controllers, etc) to feature folders:

[image: Feature Folders Organization]

So these folders can be described has follows:

1. Assets: images, fonts, ...
2. Features: list of features (blog, home, shared, ...)
   Shared hold common files to all features; A feature might contain:
   A) Angular controllers and services;
   B) ASP.MVC controllers, models, model validators;
   C) Specific CSS styles used in feature.
3. Handlers: service layer handlers that handle messages (commands, etc);
4. Helpers: infrastructure files;
5. Messages: service layer messages (commands, etc);
6. Scripts: vendor scripts (Angular, Jquery, etc);
7. Styles: global styles (reset.css, etc);

**PROBLEMS**

1. On Blog feature I will show a list of posts.
   BlogController calls PostService(?) that gets posts from the API?
   Each returned post has a title, a body and tags to display.

   On Home I display recent posts but only the titles.
   So HomeController calls HomeService or a PostService inside Post feature?
2. Imagine on blog feature I editing a new post.
   In Blog controller I call the PostService to get that post.
   But I need to fill a select list with the Tags.
   So I need a TagsService and a TagsController in Blog feature?

These 2 questions might seem strange but they help me to resolve a lot of doubts I have with this way of organizing an application.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Feature folders are great, especially in the long run.

I suggest to keep together everything related to a certain feature, including handlers.

Rethink the Services. In most cases they are not needed (unless you're exposing services for clients).

Rename Helpers to Infrastructure.

Checkout MediatR

Comment: I think what you are suggesting in present in this example from the same author of MediatR https://github.com/jbogard/ContosoUniversity. I already use MediatR but what I am missing is how to they in Contoso University "refill" the properties of the model after a submission of the model with errors. Any idea?

Comment: Take a look at the model-binders under infrastructure folder

Comment: @Miguel This is the really clever bit - there is no need to refill the properties! This is because it 'hijacks' POSTs and submits them using Ajax instead, then some javascript shows any errors on the page, or redirects on success.